# how to get Source path from symbolic file ( Script file)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have symbolic file

```
/var/application/dbm/scripts$ bala.sh -> /av/del/eb/db/scripts/bala.sh
/var/application/dbm/scripts$ ls -lrt  /av/del/eb/db
drwxrwxrwx  1 dev-env  devgrp   393 Aug 12 22:03 scripts
drwxrwxrwx  1 dev-env  devgrp   393 Aug 12 22:03 util
/var/application/dbm/scripts$ ls -lrt  /av/del/eb/db/ulti/utility.sh
-rwxrwxrwx  1 dev-env  devgrp   393 Aug 12 22:03 utility.sh
```

My question, how to invoke

```
/av/del/eb/db/ulti/utility.sh
```

inside

```
/var/application/dbm/scripts/bala.sh
```

Comment: I feel your question is unclear (you might show the `bala.sh` script). Do you know about [realpath(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) ? And what if `/var/application/dbm/` was a symlink or a bind mount? See also [symlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/symlink.7.html) & [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)

Comment: You could consider something like `rp=$(realpath $(dirname $(which $0)))` in start of `bala.sh`, but I don't understand what you exactly want to do

Answer (score 0):

If you just execute the symbolic link, it will resolve to the real file and execute that, if that file has the execute bit set for the current user:

```
robert@saaz:~$ echo 'echo hello world' > foo
robert@saaz:~$ ln -s foo bar
robert@saaz:~$ ./foo
bash: ./foo: Permission denied
robert@saaz:~$ ./bar
bash: ./bar: Permission denied

robert@saaz:~$ chmod 755 foo
robert@saaz:~$ ./bar
hello world
```